# How to retain the position in a div, or a table (tbody) nested in it in order to return to this position after having followed a link

Tags: javascript

```
<style type="text/css">

  body {margin:5px;}
  p {margin:30px 0px 30px 0px;}

  <!-- .
   .
   .-->
  #scroller {overflow:auto;height:300px;width:550px;}

</style>
```

```
<div id="scroller">
<!-- <div id="toscroll" style="overflow:scroll" align="left"> -->
<div id="toscroll" align="left"> 
    <table id="myOeuvresTable" width="593%" class= "sortable">
<!-- .
 .
 .-->
    </table>
</div>
```

bellow the table:

 Expand-->

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function openInventaireDesOeuvresExpandTblInNewTab(page)
{

    var oScroll = document.getElementById('toscroll');

    if (oScroll == null) // TJC: Invalid ID, ignore it
    {
        alert("myOeuvresTable.scroll not found!");
        return "";
    }

    var versIE = isIE();

    var x = oScroll.scrollLeft;
    var y = oScroll.scrollTop;

    alert(x.toString() + "," + y.toString());

    // result of alert 0,0

    x.scrollLeft += 100;
    y.scrollTop += 100;

    // this for testing purpose. The scrollbar does not move.

 }

</script>
```

Can you propose another method than scrollTop, ScrollLeft, not based on the scrollbar and the scroller? To facilitate the understanding of the JS 
code above, see www.danielpisters.be/ Select  in the menu on the top. Click on  bellow the second table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollIntoView` method.

`$element && $element.scrollIntoView()`